# Drawing points in top of texture openGL

Tags: c++, winforms, opengl, opentk

I have a texture drawn in a GLcontrol and I want to draw points on top of it. Instead, I get the full texture set to the colour of the point I want to draw. I guess that I have to disable the texture format and enable the points drawings, but cant reach the solution...

Here is the draw function:
Basically the point to draw is ROI[0], but instead drawing just the point I got the image shown below (the image is grayscale before drawing "the point").

```
private: void drawImg(int img){

         int w=this->glControl_create_grid->Width;
         int h=this->glControl_create_grid->Height;
         GL::MatrixMode(MatrixMode::Projection);

         GL::LoadIdentity();
         GL::Ortho(0, w, 0, h, -1, 1); // Bottom-left corner pixel has coordinate (0, 0)
         GL::Viewport(0, 0, w, h); // Use all of the glControl painting area

         GL::Clear(ClearBufferMask::ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask::DepthBufferBit);
         GL::ClearColor(Color::LightGray);
         GL::MatrixMode(MatrixMode::Modelview);
         GL::LoadIdentity();

         GL::Enable(EnableCap::Texture2D);
         GL::BindTexture(TextureTarget::Texture2D, img);
         OpenTK::Graphics::OpenGL::ErrorCode error=GL::GetError();
             GL::Begin(BeginMode::Quads);
                GL::TexCoord2(0, 0);
                GL::Vertex2(0 ,h);

                GL::TexCoord2(1, 0);
                GL::Vertex2(w, h);

                GL::TexCoord2(1, 1);
                GL::Vertex2(w, 0);

                GL::TexCoord2(0, 1);
                GL::Vertex2(0, 0);
            GL::End();
            GL::Disable(EnableCap::Texture2D);
            if (ROI[0].x!=0||ROI[0].y!=0){
                GL::Color3(Color::Red);
                GL::Begin(BeginMode::Points);
                GL::Vertex2(ROI[0].x,ROI[0].y);
                GL::End();
            }


    }
```

[image]

What should I change in my code? I can't seem to achieve it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. It seems that the color also applies to textures when binding them so I just needed to add `GL::Color3(Color::White)` before drawing the texture.

Comment: You're right, depending on the setting of the texture environment (set with glTexEnv) the vertex color may modulate the texture colors – this is then the GL_MODULATE mode. There's also another mode, GL_DECAL, which will draw the texture "on top" of the vertex color; usefull mostly with textures having transparent regions. However today everything happens through shaders and you're in charge at every step of the process (in constrast to fixed function, where you can only throw a few switches).